# jQuery slideUp/Down and fadeOut/In stops halfway

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, slidedown, slideup

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4mmk2/

Rapidly clicking the button will cause the animation to pause halfway. I suspect it's the stop() function's problem but I can't find a way to fix it.
By the way, I use stop to prevent jQuery from putting all the sliding animations in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) is deprecated you can try `slideToggle()`:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').stop(true,true).slideToggle()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mmk2/3/

Comment: Since when is toggle() deprecated?

Comment: @j08691 as of jQuery 1.7, toggle() as an event has been deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the info.
Just curious though, I've noticed that my problem persists if I set the second parameter of stop() to false. Is there a way to still solve the problem without making the animation jump to the finish?

Comment: Yes, it works on jsfiddle but not in my page. I'll try to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('a').toggle(function() {
    $('div').stop(1,1).slideUp()
}, function() {
    $('div').stop(1,1).slideDown()
})​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4mmk2/2/)**

Set the clearQueue and jumpToEnd properties of the stop method to true.